# Sublime Text 2 using Zen coding aka Emmet inside a script area

Tags: sublimetext2, mustache, emmet

When using Sublime Text 2 with Emmet (formerly Zen Coding) inside a script area (for Moustache.js) we lose the quick-codes and kb shortcuts.

The auto complete is replaced the HTML markup in to Javascript snippets, which is understandable since we are inside a `<script id="DataTemplate" type="text/html">` when trying to do HTML markup.

Is there to get back Zen coding aka Emmet quick codes while inside a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Can you provide more info? Can't you just hit undo after hitting tab?

Comment: @RyanB I dont think you understand the questions. If you create a HTML doc and then create a <scripts> and the try to use zen coding shortcuts, it does not work.

Answer (score 10):

You can use Ctrl+E to expand abbreviations anywhere: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#available-actions

Overriding Tab key for `<script>` tag (hence, for JavaScript syntax) is not a good idea because it will break your JS snippets and completions.